# Call custom function inside xslt 2

Tags: function, xslt

I want to call a function written inside xslt

this way i call it

```
  <xsl:value-of select='foo:compareCI()'/>
```

this way is defined

```
   <xsl:function name='foo:compareCI'>                                              
             <xsl:value-of select='jkhjkhjk'/>
   </xsl:function>
```

and now i have to add it to header but i what is properly way to do it?

```
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'  
       version='2.0'  
       xmlns:foo='http://whatever'>
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: What kind of value do you want your function to return? There is no context item in a function body so `<xsl:value-of select='jkhjkhjk'/>` which would try to select an element named `jkhjkhjk` will not work.

Comment: maybe you have right, this is wrong. I just want return a simple string. But i cannot call it i get this error  'Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespaces' and i think that xmlns:foo='http://whatever' this cause it

Comment: I think you are getting an error because you are using this code with an XSLT processor that does not support XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor if you want to use `xsl:function`, a minimal example for a function returning a string constant is

```
   <xsl:function name='foo:compareCI'>                                              
             <xsl:sequence select="'jkhjkhjk'"/>
   </xsl:function>
```

with a namespace declared with e.g.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo">
```

you can then call the function with e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo:compareCI()"/>
```

Comment: You need to bind a namespace URI to the prefix `foo`, you can make up any namespace URI you want, I have used one that is reserved explicitly for examples. Use something different if you want.

Comment: i get this error 'Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://example.com/foo'.'

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNJ/1 where it works and make sure you do as said: "Make sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor". The error message suggests you are trying to execute the code with an XSLT 1.0 processor. XSLT 2 processors are Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova XMLSpy/Raptor.